# installing @react-navigation/native gives error

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo, react-navigation

I have just created a new react-native app using expo init and tried installing react-navigation/native package using npm but its giving below error. I am new with react-native and could not understand this error.

```
PS D:\Subham\Private\Codes\ServiceSeeking> npm install @react-navigation/native
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! syscall rename
    npm ERR! path D:\Subham\Private\Codes\ServiceSeeking\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\react-is
    npm ERR! dest D:\Subham\Private\Codes\ServiceSeeking\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\.react-is.DELETE
    npm ERR! errno -4058
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\Subham\Private\Codes\ServiceSeeking\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\react-is' -> 'D:\Subham\Private\Codes\ServiceSeeking\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\.react-is.DELETE'
    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent 
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\subha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-11T14_52_32_403Z-debug.log
    PS D:\Subham\Private\Codes\ServiceSeeking>
```

Comment: Deleting your `node_modules` folder, installing the package and then running the `npm install` command to reinstall your node modules might help.